# Is it possible to filter Firestore data on multiple, user selected values in Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm essentially trying to build a product filter where the user can select (or not select e.g. they aren't required) from any of the filter options.

My firestore is setup as:

```
product
{
colour: "white"
brand: "a brand"
}
```

Currently I can filter on say 'colour' with this code:

```
 filterProducts(value: string){
    this.filteredProducts = this.db.collection('products', ref => ref.where('colour', '==', value)).valueChanges();
  }
```

How can I adapt the above to be able to filter on either colour, brand or both? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can query on multiple fields, the answer is "yes". For example to filter on brand and color:

```
ref.where('colour', '==', 'white').where('brand', '==', 'a brand')
```

For more on this see the Firebase documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

You'll of course need to pass both values into your `filterProducts` method in order to be able to use them.

---

If you only want to add a condition when the user has given a value for that filter, you'd do something like this:

```
ref = firebase.firestore.collection(...); // whatever you already have

if (colourValue) {
  ref = ref.where('colour', '==', colourValue);
}
if (brandValue) {
  ref = ref.where('brand', '==', brandValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted it to be possible for someone to filter on colour (1 condition) or brand (1 condition) or both (2 conditions), I'm guessing I would need separate filter queries for each of these?

Comment: The code in my answer shows how to filter on two fields. I just added an additional sample how to filter on one or both, based on whether the user entered a value for the fields.